# music recognition on windows phone 7.5 Mango

Tags: gesture-recognition, voice-recognition, windows-phone-7

There is a music recognition and voice recognition feature in Bing.

Using beta Mango, how can I access to this service and apply it to my app? Any information or approach will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest you'll get to these services at the moment is [Project Hawaii](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/hawaii/), which provides cloud-based services for text-to-speech and optical character recognitiion (OCR). However, the [Microsoft TellMe](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/Tellme/developers/default.aspx) technology (that the built-in services are built on) will be available to third party developers soon.